# Reomve all specific keys in multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like remove all keys **[Name]** but the main problem is the number in the list key ([List1],[List2] etc.). The numbers at key [List] may be more but for example I gave only two.

I would like to change this because it is an old json file and in the new one it doesn't have a key, like a converter

Is there a way to go across the entire array and remove all [Name] keys?

```
Array(
 [Values] => 1
 [List1] => Array(
    [Product1] => Array( 
       [0] => Array(
          [Properties] => Array( 
            [Id] => 1
            [Name] => Nm1
          )
        )
        [1]=> Array(
            [Properties] => Array(  
                [Id] => 1
                [Name] => Nm1
            )
        )
    )
    [List1] => Array(
        [Product1] => Array( 
            [0] => Array(
                [Properties] => Array( 
                    [Id] => 1
                    [Name] => Nm1
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [List2] => Array(
        [Product1] => Array( 
            [0] => Array(
                [Properties] => Array( 
                    [Id] => 1
                    [Name] => 0
                )
            )
        )
    )
  )
  [List2] => Array(
    [Product1] => Array( 
        [0] => Array(
            [Properties] => Array( 
                [Id] => 1
                [Name] => Nm1
            )
        )
    )
    [List1] => Array(
        [Product1] => Array( 
            [0] => Array(
                [Properties] => Array( 
                    [Id] => 1
                    [Name] => Nm1
                )
            )
        )
    )
 )
)
```

My goal is:

```
Array(
 [Values] => 1
 [List1] => Array(
    [Product1] => Array( 
       [0] => Array(
          [Properties] => Array( 
            [Id] => 1
          )
        )
        [1]=> Array(
            [Properties] => Array(  
                [Id] => 1
            )
        )
    )
    [List1] => Array(
        [Product1] => Array( 
            [0] => Array(
                [Properties] => Array( 
                    [Id] => 1
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [List2] => Array(
        [Product1] => Array( 
            [0] => Array(
                [Properties] => Array( 
                    [Id] => 1
                )
            )
        )
    )
  )
  [List2] => Array(
    [Product1] => Array( 
        [0] => Array(
            [Properties] => Array( 
                [Id] => 1
            )
        )
    )
    [List1] => Array(
        [Product1] => Array( 
            [0] => Array(
                [Properties] => Array( 
                    [Id] => 1
                )
            )
        )
    )
 )
)
```

I tried:

```
$ProductCount= count($array['List1']['Product1']);
for($i = 0;$i<$ProductCount;$i++){
  unset($array['List1']['Product1'][$i][Properties][Name]);
}
```

But I also have a key[List2] and can be [List3] etc.

Comment: show your expected output also. And what you have tried

Comment: Why do you want to remove the keys? Do you mean you want to print the array elements?

Comment: copy to a new array w/out keynames

Comment: @B.Desai added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function remove_key($array, $key)
{
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if(is_array($v)) {
        $array[$k] = remove_key($v, $key);
    } elseif($k == $key) {
        unset($array[$k]);
    }
    }
    return $array;
}

$array = remove_key($array, 'Name');
```

`$array` is your multidimensional array and `$key` is the key name that you want to remove.
NOTE: If the key represents an array (not a value) this method will ignore it but I assume that this is what you need. If you want to remove arrays if the key matches you need to switch the conditions order in the foreach loop.